# Date_Add Interval

Tags: mysql

The following MySQL works a dream when inserting rows -

```
INSERT INTO seo_task (column1, column2)VALUES ('value', DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

How can I insert a row that would be 1 Month & 1 Day? for example

```
INSERT INTO seo_task (column1,column2)VALUES ('value', DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY 1 MONTH))
```

Obviously this example wont work, but this is what I am tryign to achieve. Can anyone shed some light for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply the second DATE_ADD to the result of the first

```
INSERT INTO seo_task (column1,column2)VALUES ('value', DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

This is exactly the same as the above example, just broken out a bit for readability

```
INSERT INTO seo_task (
    column1,
    column2
) VALUES (
    'value', 
    DATE_ADD(
        DATE_ADD(
            NOW(), 
            INTERVAL 1 DAY
        ), 
        INTERVAL 1 MONTH
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Very old question, but the second simplest way to add a compound interval is jut to keep adding intervals.

I this case, the solution becomes:

```sql
INSERT INTO seo_task (column1,column2)
VALUES ('value', NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

In some other DBMS, such as PostgreSQL and Oracle, you can have a more compounded interval such as `interval '1 month 1 day'`, but not in MySQL.

MySQL does sometimes have a simpler solution to the above. There are compound units such as `interval '3 3' year_month`, but, alas, not for month and day.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps

```
INSERT INTO seo_task (column1,column2)VALUES
('value', DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH),INTERVAL 1 DAY) );
```

Answer (score -3):

```
INSERT INTO seo_task SET column2 =  NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```